# Encoding issues when reading from CSV via pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've exported a CSV-file from MetaTrader5 via MQL5 expert advisor.

```
EURUSD,2020.02.19 05:04:00,1.07991,1.07991
EURUSD,2020.02.19 05:05:00,1.07991,1.07989
EURUSD,2020.02.19 05:06:00,1.07989,1.07988
EURUSD,2020.02.19 05:07:00,1.07988,1.07989
EURUSD,2020.02.19 05:08:00,1.07989,1.0799
...
```

Now I need to read this CSV-file with Pandas. When I use the following code...

```
import pandas as pd
df_rates = pd.read_csv('D:/Rates.csv', header=None, encoding='cp1252')
df_rates.columns = ['Currency','Time','Open','Close']
print(df_rates)
```

I see 'NaN' instead of all of my data. I tried different encoding settings but this doesn't help. I have operating system with cyrillic settings. Any suggestions?

[Exported CSV-file is here](https://easyupload.io/m3lg6d).

Comment: When you run the following code, what encoding does it say it uses?
`f = open('D:/Rates.csv')` and then `print(f)`

Comment: I tried your code in my environment and all worked fine. Maybe the path to your csv is wrong?

Comment: It returns: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/Rates.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'> When I copy all the contents, create another file and paste the contents to the new file, then pd.read_csv works good.

Comment: From the `read_csv()` in your post: `encoding='cp1252'` .... From the output of `print(f)` in your comment: `encoding='cp1251'`. Might that be part at least part of the issue?

Comment: @AMC, I tried different encodings, 'cp1251' as well. Result is the same: 'NaN's and the number of lines with 'NaN's is more than data in CSV-file. When I use 'utf-8', I receive the following error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte".

Comment: MQL5 exports CSV in a strange way: I can see the file on the screen, but Pandas can't parse it. You may see the exported CSV [here](https://easyupload.io/m3lg6d).

Answer (score 0):

Encoding of the MT5 files is usually "UTF-16".

You can get the encoding of a specific file using the following code:

```
 import chardet
 
 with open(data_path + '/' + a_5_min + '.csv', 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(100000))
    print(result)
```